# Real time event handler in ZKemKeeper library not responding

Tags: c#

I have created a Windows Service to fetch attendance by using real time event from a fingerprint device using Interop.zkemkeeper library. In service Machine is successfully connected but the service is not responding to the OnAttTransactionEx real time event means that after succesfull connection to machine attendance is not fetched using OnAttTransactionEx  event. I don't know what is the problem.

Here's the code for Windows Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using zkemkeeper;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
       // private System.Timers.Timer timer1 = null;
        string filePath = @"E:\file1.txt";
        bool connSatus = false;
        CZKEMClass axCZKEM1;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            /* timer1 = new Timer();
             this.timer1.Interval = 10000;
             this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
             timer1.Enabled = true;
           */
              axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
              Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
              {
                  connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.169.9.34", 4370);
                  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                  {
                      writer.WriteLine("Machine is connected on" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                      writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                  }

                  if (connSatus == true)
                  {

                      this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);

                      if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                      {

                          this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                          using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                          {
                              writer.WriteLine("finger print Event is registered... ");
                              writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                          }

                      }
                  }

                 Application.Run();
              });
              createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

              createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();


        }
        public void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(string sEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond, int iWorkCode)
        {
           // if (OnAttTransactionEx != null) OnAttTransactionEx(sEnrollNumber, iIsInValid, iAttState, iVerifyMethod, iYear, iMonth, iDay, iHour, iMinute, iSecond, iWorkCode, axCZKEM1.MachineNumber, Tag);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" OnAttTrasactionEx Has been Triggered,Verified OK on" + "Date :" + "Enrollnumber" + sEnrollNumber + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            } 
        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
           // timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
            axCZKEM1.Disconnect();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Message is running on" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

corret version is that

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

              Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
              {
                  axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
                  connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.169.9.34", 4370);
                  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                  {
                      writer.WriteLine("Machine is connected on" + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "status" + connSatus);
                      writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                  }

                  if (connSatus == true)
                  {

                      this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);

                      if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                      {

                          this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                          using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                          {
                              writer.WriteLine("finger print Event is registered... ");
                              writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                          }

                      }
                  }

                 Application.Run();
              });
              createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

              createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();


        }
```

Comment: axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();  this code must inside the sta thread